# Setting a 2D Character Array equal to another 2D Character Array

Tags: c, if-statement, multidimensional-array

I am trying to set a specific string in a 2D character array equal to another string in a 2D character array, so that I can delete the string of my first array by inputting a NULL string in it. Is there a way to make **if(deleteCourse[0] == courseName[i])** work in my code?

```
char courseName[18][25];
char deleteName[1][25];
char empty[1][25] = {NULL};

printf("Enter your course name: ");
scanf(" %[^\n]s", &courseName[9]); // assume I input a course at row 9

printf("Enter your course name to delete: "); // typing the same name as courseName[9]
scanf(" %[^\n]s", &deleteCourse[0]); 

for(int i = 0; i < 18; i++)
{
    if(deleteCourse[0] == courseName[i]) // scanning for the same string name
    {
        strncpy(courseName[i], empty[0], 25); // using NULL, empty[0], to empty the string, courseName[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: to compare strings you must use strcmp. think about what == means in this context. what is the meaning of "courseName[I]"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For compare string, you can use `strcpm` function

```
int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

For example, in your case, you can use as below:

```
if(strcmp(deleteName[0],courseName[i]) == 0) {
    // Do something
}
```

but I saw something have problem in your code:

```
scanf(" %[^\n]s", &courseName[9]);
```

If you want to input string as input at row 9, you should not use `&`:

```
scanf(" %[^\n]s", courseName[9]);
```

It is similar to `deleteCourse`

```
scanf(" %[^\n]s", deleteCourse[0]);
```

OT, when you define the empty string:

```
char empty[1][25] = {NULL};
```

it's not exact, it means you assign to all character = `NULL` but `NULL` is used for pointer. If you want empty string, you can declare:

```
char empty[] = "";
```